# How to display images in simple listview listadapter in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I want to display image in simple listview, 
   we have arraylist **HashMap** which have values like city, description, etc.
& also the base64 image string which we have to convert to image and set to the each row of of the ListView and List row xml is `listview_row.xml`

This is my code for displaying the text fields in listview, which is done:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arllist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Intent intent = getIntent();
arllist = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("map");

int length = arllist.size();
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
{   
    try{            
        String stringToConvert = arllist.get(i).get("image");
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(stringToConvert, Base64.NO_PADDING);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.img);
        image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(productlist.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}



SimpleAdapter listadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arllist, R.layout.list_item,
      new String[] {"city", "category", "description", "mobile", "landmark"},
      new int[] {R.id.city, R.id.category, R.id.desc, R.id.mobile, R.id.landmark});

ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(listadapter);
```

My question is how to convert and bind image to adapter to display it on listview's each row
and also get's error on converting image --- bad base64

Answer (score 0):

I think [This Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRANgDgM2Zg) is exactly what you're looking for.

**Edit:**

Try this:

[Android Encode-Decode](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html)

Comment: but we don't have the images, we have base64 response in ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arllist...  so first how to convert it to bitmap as it gives "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  bad base-64" error. and how to bind it to simple adapter.....

Comment: i found that i got wrong base64 string from php service with \n and another text added at the end

Answer (score 0):

For converting Base64 string, try this-

Assuming your image data is a String called myImageData:

```
 byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(myImageData.getBytes());
    ImageView image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    image.setImageBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
    );
```

Comment: hey we are using same code as u post here but we got error  as it gives "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64" error.

Comment: in my case, its working, i guess then your base64 string is not correct somehow.